# Solving a list of equation which takes so much time

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I try to solve a list of equation in a following way but it Mathematica solves equations after 30-40 minutes or don't solve them at all. The functions that I use are ;

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ)
k[m_] := m^α
```

The equation that I try to solve numerically is ;

```
r[m_, s_] :=  pricemit - u'[(χ s + k[m])/β] k'[m]
```

with the calibration

```
paramFinal1 = {σ -> 2.1, β -> 0.8, pricemit -> 0.0005, α -> 0.5, χ -> 0.025};
```

I proceeded in the following two ways but none of them worked ;

```
sol[i_] := Solve[r[m, i] == 0 /. paramFinal1, m]
Table[sol[i], {i, 1, 15}]
```

The second way I have tried did not work neither ;

```
sol11 = Table[r[m, i] /. paramFinal1, {i, 1, 10}]
sol12 = Solve[sol11==0 /.paramFinal1]
```

These two operations take so much time or put Mathematica on "Running..." status.

How can I express this operations that Mathematica could handle easily ? Any hints, suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit : When I solve according to $s$ instead of $m$, the system is solved easily but I try to list the corresponding $m$ values for $s$ on a range between 0 and 15 (or some other number instead of 15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want this

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ)
k[m_] := m^α
r[m_, s_] := pricemit - (D[u[c], c] /. c -> (χ s + k[m])/β) D [k[m], m]
paramFinal1 = {σ -> 2.1, β -> 0.8,  pricemit -> 0.0005, α -> 0.5, χ -> 0.025};
sol[i_] := FindRoot[r[m, i] == 0 /. paramFinal1, {m, 1}]
Table[sol[i], {i, 15}]

(*
{{m -> 63.437},  {m -> 63.1679}, {m -> 62.8997}, {m -> 62.6323}, 
 {m -> 62.3657}, {m -> 62.1},    {m -> 61.8351}, {m -> 61.5711},
 {m -> 61.3079}, {m -> 61.0456}, {m -> 60.7841}, {m -> 60.5234}, 
 {m -> 60.2635}, {m -> 60.0045}, {m -> 59.7463}}
*)
```

Comment: this is impressive. Thanks a lot. I would like to know why  the code works perfectly when you write in this way the first derivatives of these functions.

Comment: @optimalcontrol I wrote them that way for clarity. Try `r[m_, s_] := pricemit - u'[(\[Chi] s + k[m])/\[Beta]] k'[m]`

Comment: You can use your equations as is (although repetitively evaluating the derivative seems inefficient). I believe the key to **belisarius's** answer is the use of `FindRoot`.