# Finding root when using Apply command

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have normally two equations system which I reduce to one equation and make its graphic. I could make the graph of the reduced equation but I can not find the appropriate command to find its root. Here is the code I use ([**from this answer**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102695/193)) ;

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ)
h[s_] := (2 hbar)/(1 + Exp[η (1 - s/sbar)])
d[s_] := (b s^2)/2
k[m_] := m^α
r[m_, s_] := pricemit - (D[u[c], c] /. c -> (χ s + k[m])/β) D[k[m], m]
```

The calibration is as follows ;

```
paramFinal2 = {σ -> 2.1, ρ -> 0.01, sbar -> 50, η -> 5.8, hbar -> 0.04, b -> 0.0001, γ -> 0.6, χ -> 0.025, ω -> 0.185, δ -> 0.0015, x -> 0.0014, β -> 0.8, ζ -> 0.5, τ -> 0.5, pricemit -> 0.006, α -> 0.15};
```

From the equation "r", I find a different couples of $m$ and $s$ which make this equation equal to zero, with starting to give 0 for $s$ (until 130) and I find corresponding "m" values.

```
sol[i_] := FindRoot[r[m, i] == 0 /. paramFinal2, {m, 10}];
tab = Table[sol[i], {i, 0, 130}];
Flatten[tab];
```

I name these values as ;

```
mylist = Last /@ Flatten[Table[sol[i], {i, 1, 130}]];
mylistrange = Range[1, 130];
```

I write the reduced equation with command Apply and plot it after ;

```
sol2adap = Apply[-χ - (ρ + h[#1]) + h'[#1]/(ρ + h[#1]) ((u[χ/β #1 + k[#2]/β] - d[#1] - pricemit #2)/(u'[χ/β #1 + k[#2]/β]/β)) + d'[#1]/(u'[χ/β #1 + k[#2]/β]/β) /. paramFinal2 &, {mylistrange, mylist}];
sol2adapplot = ListPlot[sol2adap, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

I can see that there exist one root for this last equation and it is around 16.8 but how can I find the exact value for it ? This value is for #1 but as it becomes a numerical value with apply, I can not use FindRoot or other numerical commands for a numerical root.

Comment: @Dr. belisarius sorry, I did not think to refer to your answer from the post that you have linked. Thanks for that.

Comment: It's OK.  You should always cite your sources, here and everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an interpolation function and use `FindRoot` on it.  It seems that you are plotting the value of `sol2adap` versus the index number of the list, so

```
func = Interpolation[Transpose[{mylistrange, sol2adap}]];
FindRoot[func[x] == 0, {x, 17}]
(* {x -> 16.4499} *)
```

gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I did not know that it could be made by Interpolation.